# How to reuse a SVG generated from highcharts as background

Tags: svg, highcharts

I am generating a grid, which is a SVG generated using highcharts and I want to reuse it as background of couple of pictures (`<img src=https://xxx.xx.xxx.xx/pic_1.svg>` & pic_2.svg) how to get this done?

I think might be possible to export the grid SVG to a file first then use it as a file. However, is there anyway simply save a Highchart.SVGRender or Highchart.SVGElement and use it, instead of exporting to a file, which I think will be slow I/O?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse a new string by concatenation of `data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">`, generated SVG `outerHTML` value, and then setting your`image.src` by generated string. Here is how to achieve it 'step by step':

Create new **SVG** element using `SVGRenderer` from Highcharts:

```
var dot = chart.renderer.circle(10, 10, 10)
    .attr({
    fill: 'red',
    zIndex: 99
  })
  .add()
```

Then, let's create new empty `<img>` element.

```
<img id="dot" src='' alt="">
```

And finally, set `<img>` `src` attribute by new generated value:

```
var svgString = dot.element.outerHTML
var dotImg = document.getElementById('dot')
var string = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20">'+svgString+'</svg>'

dotImg.src = string
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/864s9cwz/